# Short story about a man who synthetizes a drug that turns him into an underground monster?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I read this short story sometime between the late 1970s and the early 1980s. I read it in an anthology of weird or sci-fi horror fiction that included translated stories rather than original English stories. I don't remember the title or cover of the book.

The narrative was about a diary of a man who lives in a large house (possibly a mansion or a castle, but I'm not sure). He inherited from his late uncle old and sealed chests full of books and numerous notes. In one of those chests, he discovers a note from his uncle pleading with him to read and continue his lifetime investigations into an occult project.

The man is initially hesitant but, out of pity or to honor his uncle, decides to read about the experiment. I am sure the nature of the experiment was to synthesize a drug. Interested in the experiment, the man chooses to continue and complete it. The experiment necessitated the setting of a laboratory and the sacrifice of a boy. The man persuaded a merchant from a nearby village to lend him his son. The man took the boy to his residence and made him to drink the drug and then murder him. The man extracted an organ from the youngster (I believe it was a gland) and ate it after preparing it with other components.

I don't have clear the ending of the story. I seem to remember that the man, instead of getting the benefits of the experiment, turned himself into a monster that starts to dig galleries under the ground of the house. The surrounding area of the house begins to expand as a twisted and haunting entity. Again, I have not clear the ending of the story and it could have happened that the man dies, and the soil was affected by the failure of the experiment.

Even though the story sounds Lovecraftian, I am sure it's not (I am a Lovecraft fan).

I just recalled two more things. Following the boy's disappearance, the police searched the man's home but were unable to locate the man and the boy since they were hidden in the lab which was, I believe, in a secret basement.

Also, I recall reading about two green malevolent eyes, but I'm not sure if these were the boy's eyes after drinking the drug or the man's eyes while watching himself in a mirror after eating the organ.

Comment: Seeing as it sounds Lovecraftian; it's not an August Derleth story is it?

Comment: @bob1 - After a search of my own, I'm almost sure it is not from Derleth. I did remember a couple of things that I just added in my question.

Comment: There's one story in [The Survivor and Others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Survivor_and_Others), called "The Peabody Mansion" that has some elements - relative dies, inherited mansion, child sacrifice, documents of some sort, digging in the basement, weird dimensions. However, no monster doing the digging, and occult documents and inherited mansions from ancient relative are common themes in Lovecraftian tales.

Comment: I don't have the book but I did read information about the story at https://lovecraft.fandom.com/wiki/The_Peabody_Heritage, and I am sure it is not the story. Thank for trying.

Comment: That's the one. [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/survivorothers0000hplo/mode/2up) has it, if you create a free account.